# How to print json property name?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json in the following format:

```
{
 "nm_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Nome do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "ds_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "dt_inicio_vigencia":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Data de Vig&ecirc;ncia"}
}
```

how can I print the names of the properties using javascript? I want to retrieve the names `nm_questionario`, `dt_inicio_vigencia` and `ds_questionario`. Tried many things already but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "print"?

Comment: You'd *loop* over the properties and *print* them...!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an array of the keys with `var keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(jsonString));`. Just keep in mind that it only works on IE9+.

Comment: That was it man! It works on Firefox also! Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, sure! I mean it won't work on IE earlier than 9

Answer (score 7):

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var obj = {
 "nm_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Nome do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "ds_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "dt_inicio_vigencia":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Data de Vig&ecirc;ncia"}
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop will work. Iterate over all the indices. If you want to get the content use `object[index]`

```js
var object={"nm_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Nome do Question&aacute;rio"},"ds_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do Question&aacute;rio"},"dt_inicio_vigencia":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Data de Vig&ecirc;ncia"}};
for(var index in object) { 
    console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: already tried that. But it only outputs the number of keys. (0, 1, 2...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the names of the properties, you can loop over them like this:

```
var object = //put your object here
for(var key in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var property = object[key];
        //do whatever you want with the property here, for example console.log(property)
    }
}
```

Comment: Alreay tried that. But I only get one letter of the entire json in each loop. First iteration outputs "{", second iteration outputs ' " ' third outputs "n" and so on...

Comment: Is `object` a JSON - a string representing a JS object - or a proper JS object? If it's a JSON, you need to do `JSON.parse(yourJSONHere)`.